# Error routing user to another component after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios

I'm getting this error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

When my account logs in and gets routed to my homepage component.

How would I go about solving this error?
[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-fast-d4oj3)

```js
const SignIn = ({ errors, touched, values, status }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  // console.log(user);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status) {
      setUser([...user, status]);
    }
  }, [user, status]);

  return (
    <div className='loginForm'>
      <h1>Log In</h1>
      <Form>
        <label className='inputLabels' htmlFor='username'>
          <b>Username/Email:</b>
          <Field
            className='inputFields'
            component='input'
            type='text'
            name='username'
            placeholder='User Name'
          />
          {touched.username && errors.username && <p>{errors.username}</p>}
        </label>
        <br />
        <label className='inputLabels' htmlFor='password'>
          <b>Password:</b>
          <Field
            className='inputFields'
            component='input'
            type='password'
            name='password'
            placeholder='Password'
          />
          {touched.password && errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}
        </label>
        <br />
        <div className='buttons'>
          <button type='submit'>Log In</button>
        </div>
      </Form>

      {user.map(users => (
        <p key={users.id}>{users.FirstName} You have successfully logged in.</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const FormikSignIn = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues({ username, password }) {
    return {
      username: username || '',
      password: password || ''
    };
  },

  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string().required('Username is required'),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required('Password is required')
      .min(8, 'Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.')
      .matches(/[a-zA-Z]/, 'Password can only contain Latin letters.')
  }),

  handleSubmit(values, { props, setStatus }) {
    console.log('Form submited', values);
    Axios.post('https://bw-how-to.herokuapp.com/login', values)
      .then(res => {
        // console.log(res);
        if (res.status === 200) {
          props.history.push(`/homepage`);
          setStatus(res.data);
        }

        // resetForm();
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('Error', err.response));
  }
})(SignIn);

export default FormikSignIn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the status after you push to the route.

Your component will be unmounted after you push to history.

You cannot set the state after the component is unmounted. Switch the push and setState code and the error will disappear.

To prevent the second error, you have to skip the `resetForm();` call, if you switch the route like this:

```
Axios.post("https://bw-how-to.herokuapp.com/login", values)
  .then(res => {
    // console.log(res);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      setStatus(res.data);
      props.history.push(`/homepage`);
    } else {
      resetForm();
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.error("Error", err.response));
```

This will only reset the form, if you do not route. Because if you route, the Formik component will not be mounted anymore when you want to reset the form. This is the same kind of error as the first problem.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, so I swithed them around as you mentioned, clears that error. Now this error appears.  '' proxyConsole.js:72 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Formik (created by WithFormik(SignIn))
    in WithFormik(SignIn) (created by Context.Consumer)''